# Creating a folder (catalog) on ​the server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Controller

```
@Autowired
    private CardService cardService;

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

    public void saveCards() throws IOException {

        saveExcel(cardService.findAll(), "Report " + today + ".xlsx");

    }

    private void saveExcel(List<ECard> list, String fileName) throws IOException {

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("ECards");
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 3000);
        /...

    ..../
     ix_row++;
        }

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

In this method, I save the received data in xlsx format.

I also use a service that takes data from the repository

```
public interface CardService {

    List<ECard> findAll();
}
```

And I run it all through the class:

```
@Component
public class SaveCardsStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ECardController eCardController;

    String fileDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    String fileDate = (today.minusDays(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM"));
    String fileDate2 = (today.minusDays(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        
        eCardController.saveCards1();
    }
}
```

Now, the resulting xlsx file is saved by default in the project folder. But since this project will be launched on the server, I need folders to be created on the server, from where, if something happens, I could take information. This is a report upload project, so the folders must be created dynamically. That is, for example, the file is saved on January 10, respectively, the folder must have a name and date, at the time the file was saved. Then 11, 12... and so on. You can first create these folders on the C: for testing.

Comment: You appear to only be setting a file name and not specifying a path.   If you want it to save in a specific location then you need to set that path and not just a file name.

Comment: I thought I needed something like this:

Comment: @BrianC
String path = "C:\\ ... \\reports";
        File pathAsFile = new File(path);

        if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(path))) {
            pathAsFile.mkdir();
        }